# For Intel cpu , if chipset and motherboard are also from intel then it will give best performance. Is it true?

Tags: windows-xp, motherboard, hardware-rec, graphics-card, intel-core2

I'm going to purchase **Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E7500 (3M Cache, 2.93 GHz, 1066 MHz FSB)** and for motherboard my local vendor suggesting me to purchase **Intel DG41RQ MB** motherboard and he is also saying if i'm purchasing Intel CPU then purchasing Intel's Own motherboard with intel chipset will give best performance. Is it true?

To get good inbuilt graphic I'm thinking to purchase nvidia chipset based motherboard of any other company like Asus, Gigabyte, MSi etc. is it ok?

Although i never play games on my PC but thinking Inbuilt Nvidia graphics will be better for running Photoshop and watching **HD** or **Full HD** movies then Intel's inbuilt graphics.

or it's ok to purchase **Intel DG41RQ MB** motherborad as suggested by local vendor. Intel's inbuilt graphics would be enough for Photoshop and Watching movies.

If you know any other good motherboard for **Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E7500 (3M Cache, 2.93 GHz, 1066 MHz FSB)** then tell.

Comment: Why do you want to purchase a Core 2 series processor when it has been superseded by the Core ix series ?

Comment: @Sathya - because of my budget. CPU , Motherboard and DDR3 RAM everything is costlier for Core i3 combination compare to C2D. price difference is above 5000 INR (approx $100).

Comment: I'd recommend you post your detailed requirements over at a dedicated Indian hardware forum, such as http://www.chip.in/forums/viewforum.php?f=5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend that purchase for a few reasons. 
To answer your original question: "Is it enough for photoshop and HD movies ?" It's a no for photoshop, and a maybe for HD video. The intergrated video on the board shares memory with the cpu giving a performance hit. Performance is the factor your looking for and that also depends greatly on the HD file or media your using - if your trying to watch the latest and greatest blu-ray rip, your probably not going be able to watch that, not without an upgrade for your video card; however if your just watching something that was encoded in say divx or xvid you should have no issues. With the nvidia board you are more likely to be able to play HD video again depending on the encoding and size of the file. What I recommend to you instead is to buy the cheaper board, go to [www.newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com)
(if your in the US), and buy a cheap PCI-E video card in the range of 30-50 USD. This will almost insure that you can play back your videos.

For photoshop the minium requirements are 1024x768 display (1280x800 recommended) with qualified **hardware-accelerated OpenGL graphics card**, 16-bit color, and 256MB of VRAM. The key item is hardware acceleration your not going to get that on the built in chip, is the sole reason why it won't work or work very poorly on an integrated graphical system. For the nvidia board its a toss up but your mileage may vary on how much performance your going to get without a physical card in the pci-e slot.

Comment: then which motherboard i should purchase intel chipset based or any other chipset (nvidia, via, SIS etc) . if i purchase external graphic card , some months later.

Comment: Photoshop does not make extensive use of the GPU.  It's primarily used for display operations and zooming, but not for very many manipulations.  [Adobe TechNote 404898](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/404/kb404898.html) details exactly what PhotoShop CS4 and CS5 can use a GPU for.  The G41 chipset on the MB linked to can also do video decoding for VC1 and AVC, so there's no problem there either.

Comment: That being said, then you could potentially get away with the onboard video - I'm not a photoshop user so I just went with what they had as the min specs for the software.

Answer (score 2):

> he is also saying if i'm purchasing
>   Intel CPU then purchasing Intel's Own
>   motherboard with intel chipset will
>   give best performance. Is it true?

No, that's not quite true. Often, third party motherboards come with superior components ( better caps, for instance) more feature packed BIOS and Overclocking headroom and facility.

> To get good inbuilt graphic I'm thinking to purchase nvidia chipset
>   based motherboard of any other company
>   like Asus, Gigabyte, MSi etc. is it
>   ok?

You can't get a mix of nVidia chipset based motherboard for most newer Intel processors due to an [ongoing](http://news.cnet.com/intel-takes-chipset-dispute-with-nvidia-to-court/) litigation.

> Although i never play games on my PC
>   but thinking Inbuilt Nvidia graphics
>   will be better for running Photoshop
>   and watching HD or Full HD movies then
>   Intel's inbuilt graphics.

Some of Intel's GMA series, for instance the one present in the chipset of the motherboard you've chosen, cannot provide [full hardware acceleration for video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_X4500).

---

The dealer's probably trying to push off some of his old stocks.

Comment: @Sathya - +1 thanks for good reply. will you suggest any good mother for my choosen cpu from any other vendor other than Intel DG41RQ MB.
 or Intel DG41RQ MB is ok to purchase. and If intel inbuilt graphics cannot provide full hardware acceleration for video then is there any other vendor's motherboard can provide in same price of Intel DG41RQ MB?

Comment: @Metal Given your low budget I'd recommend you to purchase an AMD based system. I'm not fully equipped to answer that sort of a question, and I believe the question will be closed on Super User as Too Localized. As I mentioned under the question comment - you're better off asking the question in a dedicated forum ( such as the one I linked to )

Comment: @Sathya - ok then i will ask question like this on other local forums. AMD is good solution but the problem is it's not availalbe in my area. and after investing a lot of time to research about motherboard i'm thinking to purchase same motherboard suggested by local vendor Intel DG41RQ MB. becuase i think for intel cpu there is no other better motherboard than this in same price.

Comment: Intel has traditionally had excellent build quality on its motherboards.  Not a lot of options but they've been extremely stable IME.  It's been a few years since I've needed to worry about it so I'm not positive that's still the case.

Comment: @Sathya - Intel GMA Series has "Video processing hardware and software delivers enhanced high-definition video playback, sharper images with advanced de-interlacing, and ProcAmp color controls." as mentioned on this page http://www.intel.com/products/desktop/chipsets/G41/G41-overview.htm

Comment: If you check the specification update available [here](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/specupdate/319971.pdf), you'll see that the G45 chipset is the only one that has full HW decode acceleration for AVC & VC1.

Comment: @afrazier - Then should i purchase G45 chipset based motherboard for Core™2 Duo Processor E7500 cpu? the another downside for me of "Intel DG41RQ MB motherboard" is the lack of more slots for memory. right now i want to purchase 4 GB RAM which my local vendor will provide as 2 x 2GB module. so if in future i think to add more ram then i can't add with this motherboard "Intel DG41RQ"

Comment: _the another downside for me of Intel DG41RQ MB motherboard is the lack of more slots for memory_

I'd be more concerned that RAM type DDR2 is obsolete and you're unlikely to get easily in the future.

_But the problem is it's not availalbe in my area._
You can always purchase from online shops and have it shipped to where you stay.

Comment: Either a G45 board or an nVidia based board.  To be honest, I'm not sure how much decoding support is available on nVidia chipsets though since they've been running model-number hell for the past year or so.

Comment: @Sathya - If "DDR2 is obsolete and you're unlikely to get easily in the future" then should i buy 8 GB right now instead of 4 GB. because Intel DG41RQ MB has only 2 memory slots

Comment: @metal If you feel that your usage will require 8Gigs of RAM then purchase it.

Comment: @Sathya - yes i can purchase but no use for me because I've not 64 bit OS. :(

Comment: @metal Vista/ 7 32-bit keys can be used for installing & activating the 64-bit version as long as (a) the key is genuine (b) You've removed the previous install of Windows which used the same key

Answer (score 0):

Not true in my opinion. Some enthusiast-motherboards (keywords: dynamic overclocking, OC Genie) come with integrated automatic overclocking, which means they'll get some extra juice (< 5%) out of your components. The specs on the intel board you mentioned do not advertise an automatic overclocking feature.

Apart from that I don't think Photoshop or even Movies will benefit much from a built-in GPU of any kind.